# The opacity does not cover the objects which are below in Jsxgraph

Tags: jsxgraph

It seems that opacity:1 doesn't mask what is drawn before the new object. For instance, if I draw a line from a point which is also the center of a circle, I  expect that with opacity:1, I will not see the line until the border of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSXGraph uses a layer model, see https://jsxgraph.org/wiki/index.php/Working_with_layers. Higher layer means, an element is "above" another element.
Otherwise, geometry construction would not be possible.
You can either set the layer of an element class globally, as in the example, like

```
JXG.Options.layer.point = 7;
JXG.Options.layer.line = 9;
```

or set it on case by case basis:

```
var line = board.create('line', [...], {layer: 9});
```

Comment: I just have seen that this doesn't works for text

Comment: It may work for texts with the attribute `display:'internal'`.